# .htaccess URL Rewrite file extension and front controller using mod_rewrite

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I currently have a file that is removing `.php` from the URL to make it neat and much better for SEO.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

I have a page called `Main.php` and I display other pages using `Main.php?Page=page1.php`. I want to add a rule to my `.htaccess` file that will still allow my remove `.php` rule and make the `Main.php?Page=page1.php` display as

```
URL.com/page1
```

Is this possible? When I added the following line to my file my main page started loading in a loop, when I removed the line it worked fine.

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ Main.php?Page=$1.php [QSA,L]
```

Have I written this line wrong and caused it to loop?

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> RewriteRule ^(.*)$ Main.php?Page=$1.php [QSA,L]
> ```

You need to make sure you are not already on `Main.php` before rewriting the URL. That's what is current resulting in the loop... `Main.php?Page=Main.php.php&Page=Main....` etc.

Try something like:

```
# (1) If requesting a ".php" file (including "Main.php")
# or any known static resource then stop here...
RewriteRule \.(php|css|js|jpe?g|png|gif)$ - [L]

# (3) Otherwise, if the request doesn't map to an existing file then rewrite to Main.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule (.*) Main.php?Page=$1.php [QSA,L]
```

Remove the `QSA` flag if you are not passing query strings on the original request.

---

> ```
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
> RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
> ```

Your earlier directives that append the `.php` extension should be checking that appending a `.php` will result in a valid request, otherwise this will append `.php` to all your non-php requests and never reach `Main.php`. Something like:

```
# (2) Append ".php" if there is no extension
# but only if appending ".php" would result in a valid request
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.php -f
RewriteRule ^([^.]+)$ $1.php [L]
```

No need to escape the dot in a character class. And the `NC` flag is not necessary here.

---

**Summary:** So, bringing this together we have:

```
# (1) If requesting a ".php" file (including "Main.php")
# or any known static resource then stop here...
RewriteRule \.(php|css|js|jpe?g|png|gif)$ - [L]

# (2) Append ".php" if there is no extension
# but only if appending ".php" would result in a valid request
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.php -f
RewriteRule ^([^.]+)$ $1.php [L]

# (3) Otherwise, if the request doesn't map to an existing file then rewrite to Main.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule (.*) Main.php?Page=$1.php [QSA,L]
```

**UPDATE#2:** Only append `.php` to `Login`, `index` and `Signup`, instead of any file that exists. *Everything else* (including non-existent files) get rewritten to `Main.php`.

```
# (2) Append ".php" to select requests
# but only if appending ".php" would result in a valid request
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.php -f
RewriteRule ^(Login|index|Signup)$ $1.php [L]

# (3) Otherwise, rewrite everything else to Main.php
RewriteRule (.*) Main.php?Page=$1.php [QSA,L]
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for this. You said this will work on any page but Main, can that be an array? as there is 2 pages i dont want this is work on. @w3dk

Comment: As this has stopped my Login.php and index.php from working.

Comment: Its trying to load up Main.php from the start.

Comment: Sorry this is also causing page to reload :( on loop

Comment: It looks like you would benefit from more of a _front controller_ type pattern, ie. don't rewrite _any_ existing files (which will naturally include `Login.php` and `index.php`). You'll need to also make a change to your original rule that appends the `.php` extension. I've updated (rewritten) my answer.

Comment: Hello, your improved answer stops the page from going on a loop.

But if i call a page by URL.com/pagename it displays it self rather than Main.php?Page=page.php But if a page does not exisit it goes to Main

Comment: Is there a way to make all pages go to Main.php apart from Login.php|index.php|Signup.php everything else can resolve to Main.php

Comment: "call a page by URL.com/pagename it displays it self rather than Main.php" - yes, sorry, I thought that was the intention (otherwise there didn't seem much point to the "remove `.php` rule" since the two rules would conflict). Ok, so you just want `Login`, `index` and `Signup` to be handled by the "remove `.php` rule" (although strictly speaking that rule "adds" `.php`, it doesn't "remove" it - you have already removed it in your application). I'll update my answer...

Comment: This has done the trick!! no performance issues and everything goes to Main apart from the little array. Thank you so much.

Comment: You're welcome. If you can mark this answer as "accepted" (checkmark on the left below the arrows), that would be great. Much appreciated. :) (Removes the question from the unanswered question queue.)